# opensource office DOC reader

Tags: ms-office

Is there any open source .doc reader available(other than openoffice)?

i am looking for a light weight office doc reader written in C.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reader as in an application, or a library?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for reading and printing files Microsoft has it on their [site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/891090).

Comment: is the mentioned word viewer from Microsoft, open source?

Comment: It's not open source, but it's free.